# Iterating through unknown dates in R

Tags: r, date

I'm new to R (having worked in C++ and Python before) so this is probably just a factor of me not knowing some of R's nuances.

The program I'm working on is supposed to construct matrices of data by date. Here's how I might initialize such a matrix:

```
dates <- seq(as.Date("1980-01-01"), as.Date("2013-12-31"), by="days")
HN3 <- matrix(nrow=length(dates), ncol = 5, dimnames = list(as.character(dates), c("Value1", "Value2", "Value3", "Value4", "Value5")))
```

Notice that `dates` includes every day between 1980 and 2013.

So, from there, I have files containing certain dates and measurements of `Value1`, etc for those dates, and I need to read those files' contents into `HN3`. But the problem is that **most of the files don't contain measurements for every day**.

So what I want to do is read a file into a dataframe (say, `v1read`) with column 1 being dates and column 2 being the desired data. Then I'd match the dates of `v1read` to that date's row in `HN3` and copy all of the relevant `v1read` values that way. Here is my attempt at doing so:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(v1read)) {
  HN3[as.character(v1read[i,1]),Value1] <- v1read[i,4]
}
```

This gives me an out of index range error when the value of `i` is bumped up unexpectedly. I understand that R doesn't like to iterate through dates, but since the iterator itself is a numeric value rather than a date, I was hoping I'd found a loophole.

Any tips on how to accomplish this would be enormously appreciated.

Comment: So HN3 is your empty dataframe that you want to fill, and v1read is the dataframe that has the data you want. What is dat, then?

Comment: An accident. Edited and fixed.

Comment: I think  you can `merge` by `dates`.

Comment: Can you supply a few lines of what v1read looks like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's use `library(dplyr)`.  Start with

```
dates = seq(as.Date("1980-01-01"), as.Date("2013-12-31"), by="days")
HN3 = data.frame(Date=dates)
```

Now, load in your first file, the one that has a date and Value1.

```
file1 = read.file(value1.file) #I'm assuming this file has a column already named "Date" and one named #Value1
HN3 = left_join(HN3,file1,by="Date")
```

This will do a left join (SQL style) matching only the rows where a date exists and filling in the rest with NA.  Now you have a data frame with two columns, Date and Value1.  Load in your other files, do a left_join with each and you'll be done.

Comment: If you want to know more data munging you can do with `dplyr` and `tidyr` check out this cheatsheet: http://www.rstudio.com/resources/cheatsheets/

Comment: Why not just use `merge` from base R? Is there any specific reason for using `left_join` from `dplyr`?

Comment: If the OP is new to R, it's a great opportunity to start learning the data munging capabilities of `dplyr`.  `merge` would work but, in general, `left_join` is syntactical easier to use, faster and has a more consistent nomenclature with other similar tasks.

Comment: On the contrary. If the OP is new to R, first thing he needs to learn is base R. `dplyr` is optional.

Comment: That's very debatable.  Base R is clunky and non-intuitive.  `dplyr` is none of those things.  What other things should the OP not learn simply because they're in packages?  No ggplot2 graphics because R has base graphics?  Why worry about leaning tools and techniques from the onset that work better with larger data sets, have better memory management and are easier to read?  Why not start with the improved tools available?

Comment: Base R isn't "*clunky and non-intutive*". And I didn't say OP shouldn't learn packages. I just said he needs to learn base R *first*. Learning only `dplyr` without base R is like building a window before building a wall. And don't worry, I know both base R *and* `dplyr` and I'm not a college professor.

Comment: This picture describes how clunky base R is: http://tinypic.com/r/x6lx91/8

I'm sorry for the personal attack. That was uncalled for.

I still believe that if I had learned dplyr (and if it had existed) back when I was first learning R, it would have made an enormous difference in my capabilities and a dramatic reduction in my frustration.  The `magrittr` pipes are a game changer and more people should learn to think with them when they start with R instead of having to change their mindset.

I've been coaching 3 programmers through learning R and once we rolled out `dplyr` it went much better

Comment: This is working! If I have a file with columns I don't want to merge into `HN3` is there a way to perform a partial `left_join`?

Comment: In dplyr there's a select() function.  There's also what are called pipes, `%>%` which pass whatever is on the left to the first argument on the right.  So, `HN3 = HN3 %>% left_join(file1 %>% select(Date, Col1, Col2),by="Date")` where `Col` and `Col2` are the columns you want to keep. Alternatively, `file1 %>% select(-Col3)` will drop `Col3` and keep everything else.